# How an Organic Groups Admin can send mass email to all the group's members?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, organic-groups, mass-emails

I want to know if there's any module(s) that would allow any OG admin to send email messages to his group members. Just a simple email to be send to members. No need to be saved as a node, or enable comment on it.

Is there any??

I'm using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OG module should have that built in by default. There should be Broadcast tab on your group node to allow the OG admin to send an email to the group members. Make sure the OG Notifications module is enabled.